# Excel: Find a value and the copy and insert the row (containing the value) below. Then replace value with different values. All in single worksheet

Tags: vba, replace, insert, find, copy

I would like any help with this VBA code.
I want to find a value ("/m0") in a particular column(C or 3) in a worksheet and then copy that row containing the value and insert the copied row below (not overwrite the existing row). Once I have two identical rows, I need to change this value ("/m0") to 177 in the first row (in col C)and 178 in the copied row (in col C) respectively. This search needs to be done in a loop to find all the rows containing that value in  column C.

Really embarrassed to ask help here as this may be a really easy code but I could not figure it out. Please feel free to ask any follow up questions for clarification.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. You say you need help with this code, but you don't supply any code to help with. What did you try, where did you get stuck?

Comment: If you don't know where to start, you can use [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) or [For Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) to loop the rows. Knowing the [Last Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba) is useful to know what range to search & where to paste the value after [copying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) the [entire row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirerow)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.